# How can I make mock.mock_open raise an IOError?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I need to test a instance method that calls `open`.  In the first test case, I set `mock.mock_open` to return a string, as expected.  This works wonderfully.

However, I also need to test the case in which an `IOError` is thrown from this function.  How can I make `mock.mock_open` raise an arbitrary exception?

This is my approach so far:

```
@mock.patch.object(somemodule, 'generateDefaultKey')
def test_load_privatekey(self, genkey)
    mo = mock.mock_open(read_data=self.key)
    mo.side_effect = IOError
    with mock.patch('__main__.open', mo, create=True):
        self.controller.loadPrivkey()

    self.assertTrue(genkey.called, 'Key failed to regenerate')
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assign the exception to `mock.mock_open.side_effect`:

```
mock.mock_open.side_effect = IOError
```

From the [`mock.Mock.side_effect` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect):

> This can either be a function to be called when the mock is called, or an exception (class or instance) to be raised.

Demo:

```
>>> mock = MagicMock()
>>> mock.mock_open.side_effect = IOError()
>>> mock.mock_open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 955, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1010, in _mock_call
    raise effect
IOError
```

When using `patch()` as a context manager, a new mock object is produced; assign to *that* mock object:

```
with mock.patch('__main__.open', mo, create=True) as mocked_open:
    mocked_open.side_effect = IOError()
    self.controller.loadPrivkey()
```

Comment: How is this supposed to be used from within a `TestCase` function?  I've edited my answer to show my latest attempt -- perhaps you can spot my mistake!

Comment: @blz: the `patch()` context manager returns a mock. I'll update.

Comment: many thanks!  I'm new to mock, but it's actually quite simple once someone shows you how it's done =)

Comment: Do you have a SO virtualenv for each Python version?

Comment: @Simeon: just for 2.7 and 3.3.

Answer (score 7):

I found Martijn's answer a little hard to generalize, so here is what I hope is a simpler answer less tied to the OPs initial code:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open


def func_to_test():
    try:
        with open('path/to/open', 'r') as file:
            return 1

    except IOError:
        return 2


def test_open_error():
    with patch("builtins.open", mock_open()) as mock_file:
        mock_file.side_effect = IOError()

        assert func_to_test() == 2

        mock_file.assert_called_with('path/to/open', 'r')
```

Comment: It is worth noting that if all you want is throwing an exception there is no need for `mock_open()` as a normal mock will do just fine.

Comment: In this case you could change the `with patch` line for this `with patch("builtins.open") as mock_file:`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.